# CSS transition animation for moving blocks horizontally

Tags: html, css, animation, transition

I am a bit stuck implementing moving blocks horizontally. The idea is to move odd rows from right to left, and even rows from left to right. So far I have made it work somehow, but there is an issue with how blocks appear and disappear from the screen. All elements in the row should go in the loop, and after the last one again should go the first one, but it does not work and shows an empty space:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .ticker-container {
            background-color: #333;
            color: #fff;
        }

        .ticker-line-container {
            overflow: hidden;
            margin-bottom: 50px;
        }

        .ticker-line {
            display: flex;
            gap: 50px;
            width: max-content;
        }

        .ticker-item {
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
        }

        @keyframes ticker-animation-left {
            0% {
                transform: translateX(0);
            }
            100% {
                transform: translateX(-100%);
            }
        }

        @keyframes ticker-animation-right {
            0% {
                transform: translateX(0);
            }
            100% {
                transform: translateX(100%);
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ticker-container">
    <div class="ticker-line-container">
        <div class="ticker-line" style="animation: ticker-animation-left 15s linear infinite;">
            <!-- Add 10 image containers for testing -->
            <div class="ticker-item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="Image 1"></div>
            <div class="ticker-item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="Image 2"></div>
            <div class="ticker-item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="Image 3"></div>
            <div class="ticker-item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="Image 4"></div>
            <div class="ticker-item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="Image 5"></div>
            <div class="ticker-item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="Image 6"></div>
            <div class="ticker-item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="Image 7"></div>
            <div class="ticker-item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="Image 8"></div>
            <div class="ticker-item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="Image 9"></div>
            <div class="ticker-item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="Image 10"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ticker-line-container">
        <div class="ticker-line" style="animation: ticker-animation-right 15s linear infinite;">
            <!-- Add 10 image containers for testing -->
            <div class="ticker-item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="Image 11"></div>
            <div class="ticker-item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="Image 12"></div>
            <div class="ticker-item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="Image 13"></div>
            <div class="ticker-item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="Image 14"></div>
            <div class="ticker-item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="Image 15"></div>
            <div class="ticker-item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="Image 16"></div>
            <div class="ticker-item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="Image 17"></div>
            <div class="ticker-item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="Image 18"></div>
            <div class="ticker-item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="Image 19"></div>
            <div class="ticker-item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="Image 20"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: read this: https://verpex.com/blog/website-tips/how-to-create-a-css-only-infinite-scroll-animation

Comment: Thanks, @TemaniAfif, I applied hints from this article to my solution and it works as I need